# Inspect response of an async API call to a Laravel controller without returning

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm running an axios call to a controller but I want to inspect the response of the controller before or without returning from the controller call.

Since it's an async call, I can't use DD or DDD to inspect the response like I would previously do on synchronous calls.

I know that I can inspect it in the Developer Tools > Network > look for the *async url call* and inspect the response in the preview but I want to check the response in its purest form.

```
class JobsController extends Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        // This displays the available jobs
        $jobs = DB::table('jobs')->get();
        
        // I want to inspect $jobs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Job model by using command

> php artisan make:model Job

In your index method return

> return \App\Job::get();

Comment: I can certainly do a ```return json_encode(DB::table('jobs')->get());``` that but I want to inspect it in its purest form without any transformation. 

I've tried ```return view($jobs);``` but it would throw off *500 (Internal Server Error)*

Comment: Replace return json_encode(DB::table('jobs')->get()); by return DB::table('jobs')->get();

Comment: Ok create a Job model by taping php artisan make:model Job and in return Job::get() in your index method

Comment: doesn't work. but what I really want is to inspect it WITHOUT RETURN

Comment: currently i'm using console.log but I dont' really want to use that. I want to inspect in its php form. 
Anyway here's the code ```getDBJobs({commit}){ axios.get('/api/selectJobs.then(res => { console.log(res.data) }) }```

Comment: I know now, there are some BLOB and JSON columns in this table, those require some formating before returning. Thanks anyway. But I'm still curious if there is a way to inspect responses from async calls without returning the response.